# Determining which files/folders a process reads/writes from

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a closed source program which I'm running. This program is reading and writing data somewhere. I'd like to know where that is exactly.

Basically I want to run the program and somehow be able to determine which folders/files its reading and writing from. I don't mind installing third-party software to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what I/O events are happening, or [DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646) for pure I/O.

With Process Monitor you could then filter it out so you only get the file access of your process.